# How to get text filed value in JavaScript and php to insert in SQL

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to know how to get the value in text filed which sends to JavaScript and request it in Php to insert in SQL.Here are my codes,

**Text Filed:**

```
Applicant Number<input type="text" size="2"  placeholder="e.g. 5"  id="AppNum<?php $ApplicantID?>" name="AppNum<?php echo $ApplicantID?>">
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
$.ajax({
type: "get",
url: "accept.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: dataString,
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        alert($('input[name="AppNum'+key+'"]').val());

    });
 }
```

I did tried below code, but it didn't work.

**Php code:**

```
$AppNum="AppNum".$ApplicantID;

$AppNum=$_REQUEST[$AppNum];
```

I'm looking forward to your great commnets that could help me to figure out this problem. 
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is exactly the problem? The php page executes or there are problem with javascript and it blocks there without even calling the php page?
2. In the javascript code what is "dataString" that you send as parameters of the request? try an alert(dataString) before $.ajax call to check if dataString is empty or not

Comment: thanks for your reply.
1.Actually my aim is to get text filed value through JavaScript and then have it in php to do some SQL codes. 

I did it as the codes mentioned but $AppNum which is the last variable in php brings empty however I have entered an amount on text field. 
2.I want to refer dataString to text filed variable. please enlighten me if its not a correct way.

Comment: Your approach is correct. My feeling is that you miss the javascript code to retreive the content of the text field: try --- var dataString = $("#AppNum<?php $ApplicantID?>").val() --- before $.ajax

Comment: it brings me empty. where did I miss?

Comment: try alert($("#AppNum<?php $ApplicantID?>").val()); befor $.ajax; until the alert displays nothing it means you are not retreiving correctly the text input!

Answer (score 0):

How about give the variable as POST value instead of alerting it

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: "val="+$('input[name="AppNum'+key+'"]').val(),
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function(){alert('Error: cannot load page.');}
});
```

In php

```
$_POST['val']
```

Comment: did you replace page.php with the correct path of your php file?